# Ansible to create users and assign them to a particular group based on vars

Tags: linux, ansible, centos7, ansible-2.x

Gurus, I'm learning ansible and trying to understand how the variables can be used, i have come across writing below playbook but i'm not understanding How to assign a particular group to particular users based on the Variables i have defined in the play for both Users and Groups under `vars`

I have below play where i want  to create Users `anika` and `rigved` and want to assign them to a `docker` group while `ayush` and `eshant` should have the `test` group assigned.

I'm not getting the idea to achieve this so far. However as of now while running it creates users and assigns both group to all users.

```
$ cat nested_playbook-1.yml
---
- name: testing nested play
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    users:
      - anika
      - rigved
      - ayush
      - eshant
    grps:
      - docker
      - test
  tasks:
    - name: make users members of groups
      user:
        name: "{{ item[0] }}"
        state: present
        groups: "{{ item[0] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ users }}"
        - "{{ grps }}"
```

Comment: So you want to somehow join the list of users and groups with somehow the same count of subgroups? I mean split the list of users by the count of groups and then iterate over users? Why `ayush` should not have the `docker` group? How is that information stored? What if there would be 5 users? Or 13 users and 11 groups?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Sorry if you don't understand , my intent is the same as `larsks` explained, please let me know if you have any open solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've structured your data doesn't show any relationship between users and groups.  One option would be to structure it like this:

```
grps:
  - name: docker
    users:
      - anika
      - rigved
  - name: test
    users:
      - ayush
      - eshant
```

With this structure, you can loop over `grps` using the `subelements` filter, like this:

```
---
- name: testing nested play
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    grps:
      - name: docker
        users:
          - anika
          - rigved
      - name: test
        users:
          - ayush
          - eshant
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          user:
            name: "{{ item.1 }}"
            state: present
            groups: "{{ item.0.name }}"
      loop: "{{ grps|subelements('users') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1 }}"
```

The [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html) filter is a way of creating a "nested loop": it iterates over each member of the 'users' key for each group in `grps`.  During each loop iteration, `item` is a 2-tuple in which the first item is the corresponding element from `grps` and the second item iterates over the `users` key for that element. In other words, you end up iterating over this list:

- `[{'name': 'docker', 'users': ['anika', 'rigved']}, anika}`
- `[{'name': 'docker', 'users': ['anika', 'rigved']}, rigved}`
- `[{'name': 'test', 'users': ['ayush', 'eshant']}, ayush}`
- `[{'name': 'test', 'users': ['ayush', 'eshant']}, eshant}`

So within the loop, `item.0` refers to the group entry itself (and thus `item.0.name` is the group name), and `item.1` refers to the user.

```
PLAY [testing nested play] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=anika) => {
    "msg": {
        "user": {
            "groups": "docker",
            "name": "anika",
            "state": "present"
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=rigved) => {
    "msg": {
        "user": {
            "groups": "docker",
            "name": "rigved",
            "state": "present"
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ayush) => {
    "msg": {
        "user": {
            "groups": "test",
            "name": "ayush",
            "state": "present"
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=eshant) => {
    "msg": {
        "user": {
            "groups": "test",
            "name": "eshant",
            "state": "present"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Alternately, you could structure your data like this:

```
users:
  - name: anika
    group: docker
  - name: rigved
    group: docker
  - name: ayush
    group: docker
  - name: eshant
    group: docker
```

You can just use a simple loop to process this structure:

```
---
- name: testing nested play
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    users:
      - name: anika
        group: docker
      - name: rigved
        group: docker
      - name: ayush
        group: docker
      - name: eshant
        group: docker
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          user:
            name: "{{ item.name }}"
            state: present
            groups: "{{ item.group }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

---

Note that in both the above examples I'm using `loop_control` on the tasks just to set the loop label and make the output look nicer. You could remove `loop_control` from the above tasks with no impact on how they operate.

Comment: Excellent solution @larsks ..this works for me, Would you mind explaining the `item.0` and `item.1`  works .

Comment: That's just another way of writing `item[0]` or `item[1]`. I've updated the answer with some more information about the `subelements` filter.

Comment: Thank you very much @lasrks.